# Make a form from an array of objects gotten by my_model.objects.all() (for a bulk edit)

Tags: django, django-forms

Really a list of forms for each instance of the model the form is based on.... currently:

I have a list of data, currently, in the view I do a:

```
def get_booking_list(request):
    object_list = HousingRequests.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'housing_list':object_list})
```

With this I can then in my template have a nice table built:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th> User </th>
       <th> Check in Date </th>
       <th> Check out Date</th>
       <th> Room </th>
   </tr>
   {% for hou in housing_list %}
   <tr>
     <td> {{ hou.user.first_name }} {{ hou.user.last_name}} </td>
     <td> {{ hou.checkin_date}} </td>
     <td> {{ hou.checkout_Date }} </td>
     <td> {{ hou.room }} </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

This makes sense to me, I see a list of all my objects found that needed updating (I can even filter this list further in the view).  The problem is:

When a user books a room, the admin has to select which room to put them in so all the rooms say 'none', I want from the list the admin to have access to all the rooms (a list of just about 9 or so) and select which room to put each person in.

So I almost want to do a bulk edit.

I thought I could do this by also passing to this template the list of rooms in a room list, and by hand creating an option for that field in the table that has all the rooms (and a ---- if none is there) and then some ajax to see if that field was selected and to ping back to the server in a view which record had the room changed to which and do a save/update on that.

I am guessing this is the preferred way, though creating the option by hand in html using the django template tags seems laborous and I was wondering if there was a way to do this with forms somehow, most the examples I see is of the tone:

Here is your one instance of your model, here is a form for that model.  It doesn't say oh here is a form that is repeated for each instance of your model, which I guess is what I want.  I don't see any tutorials that show how this might be structured.  Or if I should just bite the bullet and roll the code to do it all by hand option boxes in html with ajax (and probably some jquery)

Comment: You can use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) to update multiple objects on the same page.

Comment: okay I just wasn't sure what it was called let me check this doc out and see if it will work (though after I typed all this up, ajax would be a better user experience)